# Unable to load signed modules on a signed custom kernel

Tags: linux, fedora, secure-boot, kernel-module

I'm using Fedora 33. In order to boot a custom kernel, I had to generate an X.509 certificate to sign the kernel. This part works just fine.

I can also sign a custom kernel module with the same certificate and I can load the module while the Fedora kernel is loaded.

But when I compile a vanilla mainline kernel with the same config as the Fedora kernel and boot it, I'm unable to load the load the custom module, even though it's signed with the same kernel.

While the `.builtin_trusted_keys` keyring doesn't list my certificate (same on Fedora kernel), the output of `dmesg` shows that the certificate has been loaded from MOK.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I can successfully use `certs/signing_key.x509` to sign and load the module, but not the one in MOK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Fedora includes this downstream patch to use platform keys to verify module signature: https://gitlab.com/cki-project/kernel-ark/-/commit/b697ff5e26974fee8fcd31a1e221e9dd41515efc